# Transparent Textured Shapes in Processing

Tags: object, transparency, processing, alpha

I'm using Processing, and I have code like this:

```
  tint(255, alpha1--);
  imp1.drawPlane();
  tint(255, alpha2++);
  imp2.drawPlane();
```

imp* are objects that are simple shapes with image texture:

```
  void drawPlane() {
    beginShape();
    texture(texture);
    vertex(x1, y1, z1, 0, 0);
    vertex(x2, y2, z2, texture.width, 0);
    vertex(x3, y3, z3, texture.width, texture.height);
    vertex(x4, y4, z4, 0, texture.height);
    endShape();
  }
```

In case you wonder, texture is just a PImage.

My problem: one of the shapes reacts as expected, being transparent to the one behind it, but the other will blend only with the BACKGROUND (pure black field) rather than the shape behind it, and will completely obscure the geometry behind it when it goes in front (and will grow progressively darker as I lower its alpha, since it's blending with the black background).

The internet has thousands of Processing transparency examples for how to make an image transparent if the background is set to something, but scour as I might, I cannot find any example that has one piece of geometry transparent to the geometry right behind it.

I'm good to do it with either OPENGL or P3D canvas type. The behaviour is the same with both.

Edit: Adding all below based off the answer about noTint().

The code now does this (and displays exactly the same broken behaviour):

```
  //before draw()
  alpha1 = 255;
  alpha2 = 1; //used to be 0, but 0 or 1 act the same
  slideZ = -1;

  //inside draw()
  imp1.movePlane(slideLR, slideUD, slideZ);
  tint(255, alpha1--);
  imp1.drawPlane();
  noTint();

  imp2.movePlane(slideLR * -1, slideUD * -1, (slideZ * -1));
  tint(255, alpha2++);
  imp2.drawPlane();
  noTint();
```

I'm also adding the "movePlane()" method so you can see specifically what I mean about the geometries moving through the Z plane.

I might try working around this bug by defining a zeroeth useless 1x1 image plane first to see if it's that second and all subsequent geometries get proper transparency (whilst the first always fades to background color remaining otherwise opaque).

Comment: Adding a zeroeth 1x1 image plane first did not change the behaviour. Reversing the order of the images also changed nothing. It really feels like this must be a bug in my code rather than Processing - eventually I'll come up with the answer and post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `tint()` will go for everything below the call, so they are accumulating... Try isolating each call using `noTint()` after it.

An example:

```java
 PImage texture;
void setup() {
  size(400, 400, OPENGL);
  texture = loadImage("http://th06.deviantart.net/fs70/PRE/i/2011/326/f/2/texture_94_3000x3000_by_frostbo-d4h03rg.png");
  texture.resize(400, 0);
  frameRate(4);
  background(texture);
}
void draw() {
  pushMatrix();
  tint(255, 180);
  makeShape();
  noTint();
  popMatrix();

  pushMatrix();
  tint(255, 200, 0, 40);
  makeShape();
  noTint();
  popMatrix();
}


void makeShape() {
  float  a, b, c, d;
  a =random(0, PI/2);
  b =random(PI/2, PI);
  c =random(PI, PI*1.5);
  d =random(PI*1.5, PI*2);


  float magA = random(15, 50);
  float magB = random(15, 50);
  float magC = random(15, 50);
  float magD = random(15, 50);

  PVector[] vtx = new PVector[4];

  vtx[0] = new PVector(cos(a)*magA, sin(a)*magA);
  vtx[1] = new PVector(cos(b)*magB, sin(b)*magB);
  vtx[2] = new PVector(cos(c)*magC, sin(c)*magC);
  vtx[3] = new PVector(cos(d)*magD, sin(d)*magD);

  translate(random(width), random(height));
  beginShape();
  texture(texture);
  vertex(vtx[0].x, vtx[0].y);
  vertex(vtx[1].x, vtx[1].y);
  vertex(vtx[2].x, vtx[2].y);
  vertex(vtx[3].x, vtx[3].y);
  endShape(CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to change the behaviour. The "first" (and one I put higher in the Z plane) always becomes more opaque and black, the "second" (and the one I put lower in the Z plane) becomes more transparent - it looks like it's becoming more black, but I move the two planes through the Z axis until they cross, and the second/bottom one (which is now the second/top one) is truly transparent and shows the one behind it.

Comment: I cannot seem to precisely define the problem here, so even though I'm not certain this answer is right, nor am I certain it's wrong. I'm calling it the right answer even though it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Its harder to tell without running your code, Maybe you could paste a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can actually see it.